# Why does visual studio terminal say "Could not restore packages" when I create a new project?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to follow the Microsoft tutorial on Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core, I'm on an apple machine, but now when I try to create a new project nothing works because none of the packages are installed and when I try to install them manually through the NuGet packet manager it still does not work is just says: "Could not add 'package_name'".

What could possibly be the reason for this?

Comment: Please add more info. What tutorial are you following? Where is the error message appearing?

Comment: @IceCode I was following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio. But I've changed to ASP.NET core 6 instead of 7 and I'm not getting the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember when I was installing the visual studio , Microsoft asked me to select the technologies that I need to work in future . Did you select asp.net core in that step of installation ?

Comment: Ask in comments instead of posts